# Why is this bash if/or string comparison not working?

Tags: bash

I am having some trouble with a script I am using to remove old branches from a repo that have already been merged to master.

I have two branches I wish to exclude and have tried this operation:

```
for branchname in `git branch -r --merged origin/master`;
    if [[ "$branchname" != "origin/master" || "$branchname" != "origin/automation" ]]; then

*** delete branches ***
```

When I run this, "origin/master" makes it into the if statement.

But if I run only:

```
if [[ "$branchname" != "origin/master" ]]; then

***delete branches***
```

then "origin/master" does not make it into the if statement, which is correct.

What am I doing wrong in the if/or?

I am running this in a Jenkins shell script btw

Comment: use `-a` instead of `||`. Firstly, you need an and expression instead of or and secondly, the syntax for this is -a/-o.

Comment: Use `&&`. See [ShellCheck's warning](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2055) about this issue.

Comment: Use `&&` not `||` — for a given branch name `x`, it is either not equal to `origin/master` or not equal to `origin/automation`, even if the `x` is actually `origin/master` or `orogin/automation`.  In other words, the condition is always true.

Comment: Wow I feel silly not seeing that. Thank you @JonathanLeffler

Comment: @dan1st — Bash's `[[ … ]]` is different from `[ … ]`.  What you say is correct for `[ … ]` but not for `[[ … ]]`.

Comment: I snipped the [tag:git] tag since as written this is a simple programming goof in bash. However, from the Git side of the equation, any time you want to work with branch names in a script, you should consider using `git for-each-ref`: this is what Git calls a *plumbing command*, meaning it's well-behaved *in* scripts. `git branch` is what Git calls a *porcelain command*, meaning it's intended for human eyeballs and may change its output format based on user configuration/preferences, whims of the Git core team, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Bash is correct, the logic of your script is flawed.
If `$branchname` is `origin/master` then it still matches the second condition (`$branchname != origin/automation`) and the entire condition is `true` because of the OR operator (`||`).

You probably want to use AND (`&&`) in your condition:

```sh
for branchname in `git branch -r --merged origin/master`;
    if [[ "$branchname" != "origin/master" && "$branchname" != "origin/automation" ]]; then
        # the branch is neither `origin/master` nor `origin/automation`
        # do something with it
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate reading rather than word split the returned string:

```sh
git branch -r --format '%(refname)' --merged origin/master |
  while read -r refname; do
    branchname="${refname#refs/remotes/}"
    case "$branchname" in
      origin/master ) continue ;;
      origin/automation ) continue ;;
      *)
        printf 'Branch %s is neither origin/master or origin/automation\n' \
          "$branchname"
        ;;
    esac
  done
```